# WI-FI adapter doesn't work on minibian (RPi1B). What to do?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, wifi, linux, minibian

WiFi-adapter Ralink RT2571MF plugged in Raspberry Pi 1 B. OS Minibian.
In minibian working as root.
I followed [instruction](https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/how-to/wifi/):

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install firmware-ralink wpasupplicant iw crda wireless-regdb wireless-tools -y
```

`$ nano /etc/network/interfaces`**:**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback<br>
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

`$ nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`**:**

```
network={
    ssid="SQT-0091"
    psk="password"
}
```

`$ reboot`
**...**

```
$ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"SQT-0091"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 20:54:76:F4:31:B7
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:2   Missed beacon:0
```

After few seconds:

```
$ iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

Look for `dmesg`**:**

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.1.18+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #846 Thu Feb 25 14:11:56 GMT 2016
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x1e400000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 126976
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0839994, node_mem_map ddfa4000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1116 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 126976 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 125860
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708.boardrev=0xe bcm2708.serial=0x416776b0 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:67:76:B0 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2708.uart_clock=3000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1fa00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 elevator=deadline root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 fsck.repair=yes rootwait consoleblank=0
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 485556K/507904K available (5792K kernel code, 488K rwdata, 1788K rodata, 352K init, 720K bss, 14156K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xdf800000 - 0xff000000   ( 504 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xdf000000   ( 496 MB)
    modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc076f1f0   (7581 kB)
      .init : 0xc0770000 - 0xc07c8000   ( 352 kB)
      .data : 0xc07c8000 - 0xc0842260   ( 489 kB)
       .bss : 0xc0842260 - 0xc08f63e0   ( 721 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:522
[    0.000000] clocksource stc: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275 ns
[    0.000015] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 2147483647500ns
[    0.000058] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 1000ns
[    0.000338] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001269] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001325] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 2.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=10000)
[    0.001412] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001790] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.001861] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.002914] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.003011] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.003079] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.003142] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.003203] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.003322] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003441] ftrace: allocating 19747 entries in 58 pages
[    0.107867] Setting up static identity map for 0x81c0 - 0x81f8
[    0.110052] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.120975] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
[    0.121435] clocksource jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.123431] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.124331] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.129872] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.131405] bcm2708.uart_clock = 3000000
[    0.136810] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.136889] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.137110] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.137397] 20201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 83, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.508609] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    0.512994] bcm2835-mbox 2000b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.559324] bcm2708-dmaengine 20007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at f2007000, dmachans=0xf35
[    0.568056] bcm2708-dmaengine 20007000.dma: Initialized 7 DMA channels (+ 1 legacy)
[    0.576633] bcm2708-dmaengine 20007000.dma: Load BCM2835 DMA engine driver
[    0.583563] bcm2708-dmaengine 20007000.dma: dma_debug:0
[    0.589746] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.593892] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.599630] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.605145] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.611159] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2016-02-25 14:26
[    0.646882] Switched to clocksource stc
[    0.700066] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.703380] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.722220] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.728154] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.735348] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.741980] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.748618] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.754516] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.761219] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.766178] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.772232] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.777007] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.781740] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.789488] hw perfevents: enabled with armv6_1176 PMU driver, 3 counters available
[    0.798626] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
[    0.821084] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.825461] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.835101] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.841884] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.847179] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.851403] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.859229] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.867219] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.871220] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.876793] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.883234] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory 5e800000
[    0.888408] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ f2007000
[    0.898865] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 82x26
[    0.910089] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 0 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.918971] KGDB: Registered I/O driver kgdboc
[    0.926148] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    0.931875] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    0.938276] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.945247] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    0.952538] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x1fa00000 mem_size:0x20000000(512 MiB)
[    0.983160] brd: module loaded
[    0.997039] loop: module loaded
[    1.002855] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xde880000, is_master = 0
[    1.013358] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.021449] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.029047] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.236625] Core Release: 2.80a
[    1.241414] Setting default values for core params
[    1.247793] Finished setting default values for core params
[    1.455081] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    1.460013] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.467476] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.474627] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    1.480613] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    1.486083] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xde814000 dma = 0x5e814000 len=9024
[    1.499229] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
Non-periodic Split Transactions
Periodic Split Transactions
High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
[    1.522450] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    1.522578] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:412: FIQ on core 0 at 0xc03dd6ac
[    1.530163] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:413: FIQ ASM at 0xc03dd988 length 36
[    1.538080] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:438: MPHI regs_base at 0xdf896000
[    1.545802] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.552472] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.561509] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
[    1.568750] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    1.574228] Init: Power Port (0)
[    1.579352] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.587814] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.596626] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.602924] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.1.18+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.610278] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 20980000.usb
[    1.617565] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.623017] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.629106] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.629128] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.629141] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    1.629204] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.629746] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.637816] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.645981] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=700000 max=700000
[    1.652783] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.660600] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.666967] sdhost: log_buf @ de813000 (5e813000)
[    1.746962] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    1.754616] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.782836] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.790798] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.798175] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.805340] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.815292] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.821624] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.827939] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    1.896040] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.908748] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.914815] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    1.921414] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    1.927855] vc_vchi_sm_init: failed to open VCHI service (-1)
[    1.933584] [vc_sm_connected_init]: failed to initialize shared memory service
[    1.944245] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning -1
[    1.954494] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
[    1.968204] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.981679] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0007
[    1.989780] mmcblk0: mmc0:0007 SD8GB 7.21 GiB
[    1.998795]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.076988] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.086203] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    2.154521] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.166291] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    2.185798] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.191904] Freeing unused kernel memory: 352K (c0770000 - c07c8000)
[    2.307457] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9512
[    2.316268] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.326734] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.332700] hub 1-1:1.0: 3 ports detected
[    2.582597] random: systemd urandom read with 60 bits of entropy available
[    2.598867] systemd[1]: systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)
[    2.616810] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    2.623976] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    2.747681] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    2.756726] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.769401] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    2.841790] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.854224] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-20980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:67:76:b0
[    2.870540] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'ipv6'
[    2.882862] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <minibian>.
[    2.957042] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    3.088191] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=2573
[    3.097137] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.116534] uart-pl011 20201000.uart: no DMA platform data
[    3.711109] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit display-manager.service, ignoring: Unit display-manager.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[    3.736751] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyAMA0.device...
[    3.748045] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    3.760156] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    3.772001] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    3.782592] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    3.791127] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    3.800974] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    3.808889] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.825660] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.839696] systemd[1]: Starting Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    3.852582] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    3.865075] systemd[1]: Starting Paths.
[    3.874077] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[    3.880830] systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
[    3.889397] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    3.895812] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-mmcblk0p1.device...
[    3.906576] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
[    3.915719] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
[    3.922635] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    3.932986] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    3.940876] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.952325] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.961393] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    3.971370] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    3.979104] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    3.989332] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    3.997547] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    4.007069] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    4.014449] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
[    4.024248] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    4.031775] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    4.041146] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    4.048338] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    4.057578] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    4.064561] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    4.080113] systemd[1]: Starting system-getty.slice.
[    4.100227] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    4.112801] systemd[1]: Starting system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    4.128575] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    4.138515] systemd[1]: Starting Increase datagram queue length...
[    4.158593] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    4.229127] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    4.264603] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    4.300067] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    4.344666] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    4.487879] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    4.541428] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    4.614927] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    4.637478] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    4.667234] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    4.692950] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    4.709471] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    4.722830] systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
[    4.751182] systemd[1]: Started Increase datagram queue length.
[    4.764417] systemd[1]: Started Restore / save the current clock.
[    4.777976] systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
[    4.807235] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    4.845836] systemd[1]: Time has been changed
[    4.977349] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[    5.201558] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    5.219341] systemd[1]: Mounting Configuration File System...
[    5.249330] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    5.283150] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    5.328747] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
[    5.373415] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    5.385725] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    5.421536] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    5.557034] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=120
[    5.937407] systemd-udevd[92]: starting version 215
[    7.694816] bcm2835-rng 20104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    8.181069] FAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[    8.274498] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    8.660322] systemd-journald[87]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    9.297145] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    9.409327] gpiomem-bcm2835 20200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x20200000
[    9.602365] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    9.609657] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    9.614114] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    9.629421] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    9.641405] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    9.653468] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    9.665621] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    9.679393] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    9.693187] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[    9.705713] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    9.718404] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[    9.737023] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_chip: Info - Chipset detected - rt: 2573, rf: 0001, rev: 000a
[    9.784532] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[    9.794618] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt73usb
[   10.610199] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup                                                               '
[   10.620564] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   10.649576] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt73.bin'
[   10.666855] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 1.7
[   10.761062] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   12.155684] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   12.165179] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[   13.497142] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   21.427753] wlan0: authenticate with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7
[   21.495326] wlan0: send auth to 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (try 1/3)
[   21.653983] wlan0: authenticated
[   21.668822] wlan0: associate with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (try 1/3)
[   21.877450] wlan0: associate with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (try 2/3)
[   21.899220] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   21.922030] wlan0: associated
[   21.926784] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   64.809120] ieee80211 phy0: wlan0: No probe response from AP 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 after 500ms, disconnecting.
[   64.871151] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   65.004976] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   65.012005] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   65.016509] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   65.031238] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   65.042886] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   65.054611] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   65.066612] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   65.080126] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   65.093778] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   65.106386] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   65.118990] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   67.699047] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   72.116599] wlan0: authenticate with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7
[   72.186444] wlan0: send auth to 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (try 1/3)
[   72.201350] wlan0: authenticated
[   72.219427] wlan0: associate with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (try 1/3)
[   72.429401] wlan0: associate with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (try 2/3)
[   72.639397] wlan0: associate with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 (try 3/3)
[   72.849397] wlan0: association with 20:54:76:f4:31:b7 timed out
```

Attempts to solve:

From //bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=96560 **:**

```
$ touch /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
$ echo "options b43 pio=1 qos=0" | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
$ reboot
```

and

```
$ touch /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
$ echo "options b43 pio=1 qos=1" | tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/b43.conf
$ reboot
```

From //ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262555 **:**

```
$ wget http://www.elektronenblitz63.de/download/wicd-1.6.x_addon01441.tar.gz
$ apt-get install --reinstall wicd
$ tar xvf wicd-1.6.x_addon01441.tar.gz
$ cd wicd-1.6.x_addon01441
$ ./install_wicd_addon
$ service network-manager stop
$ killall wpa_supplicant
$ service wicd restart
```

From //forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=160838 **:**

`$ nano /etc/modprobe.d/mac80211.conf`**:**
`options mac80211 probe_wait_ms=1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did in the first place looks OK, however you have now installed lots of incompatible software from other sites. If it didn't work in the first place this isn't going to magically fix it.

I suggest you delete all the extra stuff, or start again.

Then you can start trying to solve your problem. It is likely that this is a power issue. The Model 1B has a rather inadequate power system. Many people needed powered hubs.

It may be that the signal is too weak, as indicated in the first output.

Comment: "I suggest you delete all the extra stuff, or start again." I've installed a clean system again.

Comment: I had a guesswork about power supply. Could it work good if i turn my RPi into Wi-Fi router? Or what i must do? Change 5v adapter to any else with more ampers? Because adding a hub with external power is not the best way for me.

Comment: Provided the PSU is OK, changing to a higher rated one won't help - the current is limited by the polyfuse. You don't say exactly what model PI. The Pi B Release 2 could supply 500mA to USB, earlier models less. I would try a powered hub to test. I suspect low signal. No amount of fiddling with the software is going to make it any better. Try `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` to see if your adapter can see any networks.